# How to access port of one container in other docker containers with localhost in the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can access the docker container port in local machine with localhost with port mapping, but it is not accessible in other containers in a similar way.

My docker-compose file creates a Ubuntu and Nginx containers with 80:80 port mapping. When I try to access the Nginx URL from Ubuntu, the port refuses the connection. I can access the port with container name but not with localhost.

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml file content

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
      image: nginx
      ports:
       - "80:80"
      links:
        - userver
      depends_on:
        - userver

    userver:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile content

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y net-tools curl
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

```
docker-practice $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
c3f06dc519d8        nginx                     "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 hours ago         Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   docker-practice_web_1
40324fa76612        docker-practice_userver   "/bin/sh -c 'tail -f…"   4 hours ago         Up 10 minutes       80/tcp               docker-practice_userver_1
```

Accessing Nginx URL from local host with localhost

```
docker-practice $ curl http://localhost -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2019 03:35:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 14:04:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c9a3176-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Accessing Nginx URL from Ubuntu container with localhost

```
root@40324fa76612:/# curl http://localhost -I
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

Accessing Nginx URL from Ubuntu container with container name

```
root@40324fa76612:/# curl http://docker-practice_web_1 -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.10
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2019 03:42:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Mar 2019 14:04:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c9a3176-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I expect the port access in Ubuntu docker container with localhost, but the port is refusing connections.

Comment: From within the docker-compose (network) `userver` may reference the Nginx container by its service name `web` on port 80: `curl --head http://web`

Comment: **NB** `links` is deprecated in docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Answer (score 0):

A container acts like a machine (computer) on its own. So if you enter a container and call "localhost" then localhost points to that container. The whole idea of a container is to "contain" its environment. Try to not use localhost anymore when working with containers.

Use either container names or service names (when in a docker-compose network).